# Deploying Simple Spring Hibernate Utility Project via Maven to Tomcat

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

My goal is understanding the J2EE lifecycle at a high-level with Spring, Hibernate, and Maven. From much research, I understand that Spring provides dependency injection and Hibernate provides object-relation mapping with databases. Maven is a tool to improve the build/deployment process from my understanding. With that said, everywhere I search I get more and more lost on configuration files (i.e. pom.xml, server.xml, etc.), terminology, and alternatives such as Gradle. I just want to build and launch the application and be able to see via `http://localhost:8080` in tomcat.

At first, I couldn't get the default project (picture attached) built, but after further research found that I needed to Maven clean and Maven install.

[image: New Spring Project]

[image: Maven clean]

[image: Maven Install]

I also modified settings in pom.xml changing version numbers and the database to use MySQL.

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

The next issue I had was in OrderPersistenceTests.java it used org.hibernate.classic.Session which is no longer the correct class path and found that it needed to be org.hibernate.Session.

Finally, I was able to get it to build but cannot figure out how to deploy to Tomcat from Spring Tool Suite.

Comment: try running "Run As" -> "Maven build..."  with the goal: `tomcat7:run`

Comment: I get this error: No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together a simple example using Maven, Spring, Hibernate, and ExtJS for the front end at the following link:

https://github.com/drembert/java-webapp-sample

If you are using Spring Source Tool Suite which it looks like you are in the screen shot, you should be able to import everything using the "Import Maven Projects" option. The example uses Hypersonic as the in-memory DB to allow easier deployment. Keep in mind this example generates two different .war files (one is presentation-layer and the other is service-layer) to emulate a simple RESTful service so both will need to be deployed to the Spring tcServer (STS's version of Tomcat), but once they are you should be able to view the GUI at `http://localhost:8080/presentation-layer`. Another thing to make note of is that this example currently doesn't have a security layer which would normally be implemented using Spring security, but I am working on adding that in the near future.